# Python/MongoDB dashboard loading but filters/map will not

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook

I have spent several hours each day for the last 3 days trying to get this code to function properly. While it running has not been an issue, I have been having issues with the filtering of the data when the options are clicked and the map doesn't appear. I am using Jupyter Notebook for testing/development and am open to any and all suggestions.

Dashboard.py/.ipynb

```
from jupyter_plotly_dash import JupyterDash

import dash
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import plotly.express as px
from dash import dash_table as dt
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps
import base64

# Importing AnimalShelter class 
from AnimalShelter_AMizway import AnimalShelter





###########################
# Data Manipulation / Model
###########################
username = 'aacuser'
password = 'SNHUdb'
animals = AnimalShelter()


# class read method must support return of cursor object 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(animals.read({}))





#########################
# Dashboard Layout / View
#########################
# create dash application

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


image_filename = 'GraziosoSalvareLogo.png' # replace with your own image
encoded_image = base64.b64encode(open(image_filename, 'rb').read())
                               
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='hidden-div', style={'display':'none'}),
    html.Center(html.B(html.H1('SNHU CS-340 Dashboard'))),
    html.Center(html.B(html.H1('Alex Mizway Project 2 Dashboard'))),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Img(id='customer-image',src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode()),alt='customer image'),
    html.Div(      
        dcc.RadioItems(
            id='filter-type',
            options=[
                {'label': 'Water Rescue', 'value': 'water'},
                {'label': 'Mountain/Wilderness Rescue', 'value': 'mount'},
                {'label': 'Disaster Rescue and Individual Tracking', 'value': 'disaster'},
                {'label': 'Reset', 'value': 'reset'}
            ],
            value='reset'
        )
        
    ),
    html.Hr(),
    dt.DataTable(
        id='datatable-id',
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        # Allows 10 rows per page, and starts on page 0. Columns and Rows may be selected but not deleted/edited
        editable=False,
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode="multi",
        column_selectable=True,
        row_selectable=True,
        row_deletable=False,
        selected_columns=[],
        selected_rows=[0],
        page_action="native",
        page_current= 0,
        page_size= 10,
    ),
    html.Br(),
    html.Hr(),
#This sets up the dashboard so that your chart and your geolocation chart are side-by-side
    html.Div(className='row',
         style={'display' : 'flex'},
             children=[
        html.Div(
            id='graph-id',
            className='col s12 m6',

            ),
        html.Div(
            id='map-id',
            className='col s12 m6',
            )
        ])
])

#############################################
# Interaction Between Components / Controller
#############################################



# Radio button filters
@app.callback([Output('datatable-id','data'),
               Output('datatable-id','columns')],
              [Input('filter-type', 'value')])
def update_dashboard(filter_type):
        # Water Rescue filter
        if filter_type == 'water':
            df = pd.DataFrame(list(shelter.read({'$and': [{'sex_upon_outcome': 'Intact Female'},
                                                        {'$or': [
                                                        {'breed': 'Labrador Retriever Mix'},
                                                        {'breed': 'Chesa Bay Retr Mix'},
                                                        {'breed': 'Newfoundland Mix'},
                                                        {'breed': 'Newfoundland/Labrador Retriever'},
                                                        {'breed': 'Newfoundland/Australian Cattle Dog'},
                                                        {'breed': 'Newfoundland/Great Pyrenees'}]},
                                                        {'$and': [{'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$gte': 26}},
                                                        {'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$lte': 156}}]
                                                        }]
                                                })))
        #adjusts the read request for the desired dog type and status
        elif filter_type == 'mount':
            #Grazioso breeds and ages
            df = pd.DataFrame(list(shelter.read({'$and': [{'sex_upon_outcome': 'Intact Male'},
                                                          {'$or': [
                                                              {'breed': 'German Shepherd'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Alaskan Malamute'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Old English Sheepdog'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Rottweiler'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Siberian Husky'}]
                                                          },
                                                          {'$and': [{'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$gte': 26}},
                                                                    {'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$lte': 156}}]
                                                          }]
                                                })))
        #adjusts the read request for the desired dog type and status
        elif filter_type == 'disaster':
            #breeds and ages
            df = pd.DataFrame(list(shelter.read({'$and': [{'sex_upon_outcome': 'Intact Male'},
                                                          {'$or': [
                                                              {'breed': 'Doberman Pinscher'},
                                                              {'breed': 'German Shepherd'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Golden Retriever'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Bloodhound'},
                                                              {'breed': 'Rottweiler'}]
                                                          },
                                                          {'$and': [{'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$gte': 20}},
                                                                    {'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$lte': 300}}]
                                                          }]
                                                })))
        #resets the search no filter
        else:
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.read({}))

        
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns]
        data=df.to_dict('records')
        
        return (data,columns)

# Change background color of selected columns
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-id', 'style_data_conditional'),
    [Input('datatable-id', 'selected_columns')]
)
def update_styles(selected_columns):
    return [{
        'if': { 'column_id': i },
        'background_color': '#D2F3FF'
    } for i in selected_columns]

# Chart
@app.callback(
    Output('graph-id', "children"),
    [Input('datatable-id', "derived_viewport_data"),
     #Input('filter-type', 'value')
    ])
def update_graphs(viewData):
    ###FIX ME ####
    # add code for chart of your choice (e.g. pie chart) #
    dff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(viewData)
    
    return [
        dcc.Graph(            
#             figure = px.pie(dff, values='breed',  
#                             title='Available Dogs by Breed')
            figure = px.histogram(dff, x='breed')
        )    
    ]

# Map
@app.callback(
    Output('map-id', "children"),
    [Input('datatable-id', "derived_viewport_data"),
     Input('datatable-id', 'derived_viewport_selected_rows')])
def update_map(viewData, row_ids):
    dff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(viewData)
    # Sets first num in row_ids array to the last selected row ID
    row_ids[0] = row_ids[len(row_ids) - 1]
    return [
        # row_ids[0] gets last selected row from DataTable and parameters 13 and 14 are long and lat of rows
        dl.Map(style={'width': '1000px', 'height': '500px'}, center=[dff.iloc[row_ids[0],13],dff.iloc[row_ids[0],14]], zoom=10, children=[
            dl.TileLayer(id="base-layer-id"),
            # Marker with tool tip and popup
            dl.Marker(position=[dff.iloc[row_ids[0],13],dff.iloc[row_ids[0],14]], children=[
                # parameter num 4 gives the breed of animal
                dl.Tooltip(dff.iloc[row_ids[0],4]),
                dl.Popup([
                    html.H1("Animal Name"),
                    # parameter 9 gives animal's name
                    html.P(dff.iloc[row_ids[0],9])
                ])
            ])
        ])
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

and in case it helps, here is the python file that allows for the interaction between the MongoDB server and the dashboard.

AnimalShelter_AMizway.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """
    
    def __init__(self):
        USER = 'aacuser'
        PASS = 'SNHUdb'
        HOST = 'nv-desktop-services.apporto.com'
        DB = 'AAC'
        COL = 'animals'
        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@%s:31831' % (USER, PASS, HOST))
        self.database = self.client['%s' % (DB)]
        self.collection = self.database['%s' % (COL)]

    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            insert = self.database.animals.insert_one(data)
            null = None
            if insert != 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")

    def read(self, search_criteria=None): #left default criteria empty
        if search_criteria:
            animal_query = self.database.animals.find(search_criteria, {"_id": False}) #returns documents matching criteria while removing the ID of each document
        else: #returns all documents
            animal_query = self.database.animals.find({}, {"_id": False})
        return animal_query

    def update(self, data, new_values):
        if self.database.animals.count(data):
            self.database.animals.update(data, new_values)
            temp = self.database.animals.find({"_id": False})
            return temp
        else:
            print("Does not exist")

    def delete(self, data):
        result = self.database.animals.delete_many(data)
        if(result):
            print("deleting")
        else:
            print("Nothing to delete")
```

I have already tried using different techniques of getting the map/filters to load but all attempts ended with the dashboard not opening at all and stating that `AttributeError: 'JupyterDash' object has no attribute 'run_server'`.